# How to get Text Form Output in the result

Tags: javascript, html, forms

i have a code the drop downs are working fine... but i want the Text thats typed in the text box to output after the $s= in the results here is the code that is being used

http://jsfiddle.net/Webbytest/ygz32s0u/

```js
$("#month, #color").change(function() {
  var month = $("#month").val();
  var color = $("#color").val();
  var content = '';
  if (month && color) {
    var monthlabel = $("label[for=" + month + "]").text();
    var colorlabel = $("label[for=" + color + "]").text();
    content = ' ' + monthlabel + '' + colorlabel + '&s=';
  }
  $("#output").text(content).fadeIn();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

form {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 370px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px/18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.output {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px/20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #009CDC;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.17em;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: true;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>test header</h2>

<p>blahblah.</p>

<form>
  <select id="month">
    <option value="caeqweqwm1">Select NUMBER</option>
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>

  </select>
  <label class="1" for="1">/bookmark1.php?f=</label>
  <label class="2" for="2">/bookmark2.php?f=</label>
  <label class="3" for="3">/bookmark3.php?f=</label>
  <label class="4" for="4">/bookmark4.php?f=</label>
  <label class="5" for="5">/bookmark5.php?f=</label>



  <select id="color">
    <option value="qwq">Select Date</option>
    <option value="6-28-18">6-28-18</option>
    <option value="6-29-18">6-29-18</option>
    <option value="6-30-18">6-30-18</option>
    <option value="7-1-18">7-1-18</option>

  </select>
  <label class="6-28-18" for="6-28-18">062818xdasddA</label>
  <label class="6-29-18" for="6-29-18">062918x31ewqeqwe</label>
  <label class="6-30-18" for="6-30-18">063018x3123233</label>
  <label class="7-1-18" for="7-1-18">070118x23232</label>
  <input name="formtext1" type="text">
  <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: Please show an example output and where you want it. In the P?

Comment: its in fiddle the drop downs are working its just that text box after you select a date and a number it will have like /bookmark2.php?f=063018x3123233&s= i want what ever is typed into the text box to be after the s=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full disclosure: I'm not a user of JQuery. If I had to do it, this is (maybe) how I'd do it with hand-written ES5. Note the event listener we're watching for is 'input' instead of 'change' as it seems to work better for all inputs involved.

The entire handler is encapsulated in a function to avoid colliding with JS outside of the function. I also changed the value of your "SELECT a whatever" option to an empty string to test for falsy input values.

```js
function fieldChangeHandler(){ 
  var values = {
    month: '',
    color: '',
    search: ''
  }
  
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  
  function outputString(){
    output.innerHTML = values.month + values.color + values.search;
  }
  
  function updateValue(e) {
    switch(e.target.id) {
      case 'search':
        values[e.target.id] = e.target.value ? 
          '&s='+encodeURI(e.target.value) : '';
        break;
      default:
        values[e.target.id] = e.target.value ? 
          document.querySelector('label[for="'+e.target.value+'"]').innerHTML : '';
    }
    outputString();
  }

  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.form_field');
  inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(inputs);
  inputs.forEach(function(input){
    input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
  });

}

fieldChangeHandler();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

form {
  margin: 0px auto;
  width: 370px;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px/18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.output {
  color: #000;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px/20px;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  color: #009CDC;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 2.5em;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 100;
  line-height: 1.17em;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: true;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>test header</h2>

<p>blahblah.</p>

<form>
  <select id="month" class="form_field">
    <option value="">Select NUMBER</option>
    <option value="1"> 1</option>
    <option value="2"> 2</option>
    <option value="3"> 3</option>
    <option value="4"> 4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>

  </select>
  <label class="1" for="1">/bookmark1.php?f=</label>
  <label class="2" for="2">/bookmark2.php?f=</label>
  <label class="3" for="3">/bookmark3.php?f=</label>
  <label class="4" for="4">/bookmark4.php?f=</label>
  <label class="5" for="5">/bookmark5.php?f=</label>



  <select id="color" class="form_field">
    <option value="">Select Date</option>
    <option value="6-28-18">6-28-18</option>
    <option value="6-29-18">6-29-18</option>
    <option value="6-30-18">6-30-18</option>
    <option value="7-1-18">7-1-18</option>

  </select>
  <label class="6-28-18" for="6-28-18">062818xdasddA</label>
  <label class="6-29-18" for="6-29-18">062918x31ewqeqwe</label>
  <label class="6-30-18" for="6-30-18">063018x3123233</label>
  <label class="7-1-18" for="7-1-18">070118x23232</label>
  <input id="search" class="form_field" type="text">
  <p id="output"></p>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Webbytest/pc2e04ht works but question how would i add http://blahblah.com at the start of the output and how would i make it if cam 1 is selected it shows cam 1 but if cam 2 is selected it replaces the cam1 with cam 2's in the output instead of puts it in front of it

Comment: Also how would i make this output as a iframe instead of as a line of text

Comment: Note that I added a function to the handler that clears other selection fields when a new one is changed. Changing the src of an iframe can done with the element.setAttribute() method. You'll have to use the inspector to see the change, but it works.

Comment: Why is the iframe so tiny i tried adding the size to 640 w by 460H but didnt work

Comment: It's contained inside of the form element that has a fixed width of 370px

Answer (score 0):

1. You aren't considering the changes on input, or reading their values.
   `$("#month, #color")` --> `$("#month, #color, input[name='formtext1'")`
2. The value of the input: `$("[name='formtext1']").val();`

http://jsfiddle.net/ygz32s0u/7/

Another alternative is to add an ID to the input for more precise selection:
http://jsfiddle.net/ygz32s0u/13/

Comment: Works! your awesome

Comment: Fair warning, if you select only on name...there might be problems if future elements have the same name. You might want to consider using an ID to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: Another Question what if i wanted to take the final output and load it in a iframe like instead of having /bookmark2.php?f=062918x31ewqeqwe&s=sass display as text under the form what if i wanted to have it as a iframe code inside the html?

Comment: Put an iframe on the page, change the source.
`document.getElementById('myIframe').src = "http://www.google.com" + content.trim();`
http://jsfiddle.net/ygz32s0u/18/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7o4v0q8y/ Any idea whats broke in this? Im trying so if cam 1 date is chosen and &s=what ever in text field it displays cam 1 info but if cam 2 date is chosen cam 2 info with what ever is in the text field

Comment: Your condition is only on the first `cam`, I'd update it like so:
`const cam = cam1 || cam2 || cam3 || cam4 || cam5
    if (cam && color) {
      content = ' ' + cam + '&s=' + formtext;
    }`

shortcircuiting will take the first valid cam